# Would you mind LET/LETTING?

Tags: verb-forms

Which one is correct:

> 1. Would you mind **let** me finish, please?
> 2. Would you mind **letting** me finish, please?

In this short video below, a native speaker says "Would you mind let me finish, please?" I'm just wondering about whether or not "Would you mind **let**" can be used in Common core English, while "Would you mind **letting**" is formal?

http://www.tubechop.com/watch/1294497

Answer (score 6):

I watched/listened to the video.  She actually says, "let'm me finish" which is a slurred *letting me*- she's speaking quickly because she's trying to cut off the other man being interviewed.  Couple that with her accent and it almost becomes completely lost.

Prior to watching the video  I had surmised that what I'd find was someone saying:

> Would you mind?  Let me finish, please.

Comment: +1 But I hear it as /leʔnme/, with the /t/ elided into the /n/ but still "represented" by the glottal stop which accompanies it.

Comment: What @StoneyB said. She definitely produces a glottal stop followed by /n/ between the two stressed components. Probably easier for me to hear because it's *very* common in British casual speech. In my "mind's ear", I imagine most Americans in such contexts speaking more slowly anyway, and coming out with something more like *"Would you mind **leaden** me finish"*, but maybe that's just a stereotype.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you asked the reporter she'd claim to have said "letting".

It is very common for native speakers not to pronounce the "g" sound of words such as letting, coming out with something closer to "letten".  In extreme cases the "en" sound is shortened or swallowed so that it's barely audible, as I believe is the case here.

Comment: My guess is that it's primarily the glottal stop that OP doesn't hear, but you're right that she's saying "letting".